# openByURL opens first value and arrays down selected column

Tags: google-apps-script

This will only open F2 and will array that value down column G...help?

```
function CountData() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp;
var urlsheet = sheet.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var url = urlsheet.getRange('F2:F100').getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<url.length;++i){
       var formsheet = sheet.openByUrl(url);
       var CountRows = formsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
       urlsheet.getRange('G2:G').setValue(CountRows);
}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping through the array, but you're not using the actual value. Keep in mind that [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2-dimensional array, so you need to access the value using `[i][0]`.

```
function CountData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp;
  var urlsheet = sheet.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var urls = urlsheet.getRange('F2:F100').getValues(); // Renamed to be plural, indicating some kind of list
  for(var i=0;i<urls.length;++i){
    var formsheet = sheet.openByUrl(urls[i][0]); // Select the URL
    // ... the rest of your code
  }
};
```

I think the rest of the code in your for-loop will have issues because

1. The script is not [container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to `formsheet`, so you can't access [`.getActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#special_methods). Try something like [`.getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)) instead.
2. You're not updating the range `urlsheet.getRange('G2:G')`, so you're going to be replacing the values in that column for every url.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I see an error at "openByUrl(urls[i][0];" with those adjustments and the same arrayed values down column G with the getSheetByName. Do you have anything to explain why I am seeing your 2nd comment? "You're not update the range urlsheet.getRange('G2:G'), so you're going to be replacing the values in that column for every url." Is there a workaround for this? I have tried to assign the row, column, mrow, and mcol without success and tried giving them an anchor.

Comment: @MetPasta What error are you getting? With regards to Col G, yes, you should be assigning the row & column. If you show that code, then we can help you figure out what's going wrong there too.

Comment: there's an error at "openByUrl(urls[i][0]);" that is: Exception: Invalid argument: url at CountData(New:6:27) and the results change from the F2 value being arrayed down column G to F3 being arrayed down column G (in the example table that I am working with, there are only two values F2/F3)

Comment: @MetPasta That error is because you're passing in an empty string, given that you only have 2 values but are passing in range F2:F100. Use a condition to prevent that or adjust your range.

Comment: @MetPasta Regarding your results, that just sounds like you're not assigning the correct range.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking into a condition that will work now

Answer (score 1):

```
function CountData() {
  var ush=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var uv=ush.getRange(2,6,99,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var rA=[];
  uv.forEach(function(url){rA.push([SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getActiveSheet().getLastRow()])});
  ush.getRange(2,7,rA.length,rA[0].length).setValues(rA);
}
```